# Best Practices for using writing versions in Android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin, kotlin-android-extensions

I am fairly new to Android Development.. I can remember vaguely, that when I newly started Android Studio usually defined some versions of api/extensions in `ext` in the project level of `build.gradle`.

Something like this: (in the project level)

```
ext {
    activityVersion = '1.2.3'
    appCompatVersion = '1.3.0'
    constraintLayoutVersion = '2.0.4'
}
```

And something like in the App level:

```
implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$rootProject.appCompatVersion"
implementation "androidx.activity:activity-ktx:$rootProject.activityVersion"
```

But just very recently I discovered they just specify the version directly.

Like so:

```
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
```

I am asking all this because I am working on a project and I intend to to follow best practices, A tutorial I watched vassly followed the first method which draw my attention to it..

So which brings me to ask **what is the best practice, to just explicitly write the versions or what??**

I appreciate all your understanding and feedback.. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

It's good practice to write all the version in ext.

Reason:
if multiple modules using the same library then defining the version at one place will make you easy to update across all places.